# Why is a map to a smaller dimensional space not injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to proof the theorem that states that:

"A map to a smaller dimensional space is not injective"

So I first suppose that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces such that $\dim V > \dim W$ and I let $T$ be the linear transformation from $V$ to $W$.

Given the above, you have that:

$\dim(\operatorname{null}(T)) = \dim(V) - \dim(\operatorname{range}(T)) \geq \dim(V) - \dim(W) > 0$

So I understand the first and second equalities. However, I don't understand why $\dim(V) - \dim(W)$ is strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: This is common sense really. If we have three linearly independent vectors and we can map them to three independent vectors, then the codomain must be at least three dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming $\dim V>\dim W$, so $\dim V-\dim W>0$.

Comment: Oh right, can't believe I couldn't see that...

Answer (score 0):

I see that the question has been answered, but here is some added clarification that I found helpful while learning the proof for this question.

Here's Axler's proof:

> *Let T be a linear map from V to W where dimV > dimW*
>
> *dimNullT = dimV - dimRangeT*
>
> *dimNullT >= dimV - dimW*
>
> *dimNullT > 0*
>
> ** This implies that vectors other than **0** are in *nullT* so T is not injective.

Note that If *nullT = {**0**}* then *dimNullT = 0* which is why ** is true; and we should remember that the dimension of the zero vector is 0.